# Sum of Absolute Values

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was going over a question and I wanted your opinion(s) on it:

> > The product of two numbers is 6 and one of the numbers is 5 less than the other. What is the absolute value of the sum of the two numbers?

The numbers I got are 1 and -6 because $b(b+5)=6$.
Now the sum of absolute values would be $|1-6|$, right, so 5?
According to the book the answer is 7. Apparently the book expects me to do $|1| + |-6| = 7$.
Am I right and the answer in the book is wrong?

Edit:
It seems my numbers are wrong, here is how I got them. Please correct me if I am wrong.

$$(b+5)(b) = 6$$

so I get $$b^2 + 5b -6 = 0 $$

$b= 1$ and $b=-6$ by solving the quadratic equation.

Comment: If the book is asking for the sum of the absolute values, as your title suggests, then 7 is the correct answer. If the book is asking for the absolute value of the sum, then 5 is correct.

Comment: The numbers are wrong: $1\cdot(-6)=-6\neq6$. Also, the difference between $1$ and $-6$ is $7$, not $5$.

Comment: So they are - I assumed he had at least done that bit right!

Comment: Sorry i was suppose to enter those values back in the equation.

Comment: Your solution of the quadratic is correct, which means that the smaller of the two numbers is either -6 or 1.
In the first case, the two numbers would be -6 and -1, whereas in the second case, the numbers would be 1 and 6.
In either case, the sum of the absolute values and the absolute value of the sum are both equal to 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x$ be the smaller of the numbers, so the other is $x+5$. We have the equation
$$
x(x+5)=6.
$$
Solve for $x$ and check that $|x+(x+5)|=7$ no matter which solution of the quadratic you use as $x$.